# Обрезать начало в значении переменной

Tags: php

Есть переменная

```
$imurl = "http://site.ru/images/img.jpeg";
```

Нужно обрезать начало `"http://site.ru"` и записать получившийся результат (`/images/img.jpeg`) в другую переменную.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/gOB6xV

```
<?php

$imurl = "http://site.ru/images/img.jpeg";

$imurl_relative = str_replace('http://site.ru', '', $imurl);

echo $imurl."\n";
echo $imurl_relative;
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо.

Answer (score 2):

Более универсальное решение. [Функция для работы с URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
 $imurl = "http://site.ru/images/img.jpeg"; 
 $same = parse_url($imurl);
 echo $same[path];
```

Comment: А я уж грешным делом хотел порекомендовать explode() и implode(), спасибо за полезную функцию, думаю 100% пригодится в работе.